# How can you, if even possible, Store binary image data within memcached?

Tags: php, image, memcached

I am developing a program to store binary image data, and I've decided to use memcached for the cache layer. I don't actually get any error but when I store the binary data in it doesn't quite work.[This is what the output of the array is , Look closely at where it says Profile_Pic, the value is just one character](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mQdCu.png)

```
        This is the code I use to update the memcaches array. Note that storing regular 
        values in memcached works fine.
        <?php $unit_array=$this->Memc->getByKey("Unit_Array_Casting_Server",$unit_name);
        $unit_array[$uuid][$keyname]=$keyvalue;
        $this->Memc->setByKey("Unit_Array_Casting_Server",$unit_name,$unit_array); ?>
```

Comment: Have you tried to base64 the binary data before storing it?

Comment: Yes, I have but the result is the same

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Nevermind, it turns out the issue was a internal code issue, I was inputing $keyvalue variable as an array which it is not.